# PHP - Как заменить mysql connect на PDO connect?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
function sql($login='root', $pass='', $db='test', $host = '')
    {           
        $this->connect = mysql_connect($host, $login, $pass) or die('MYSQL OK.');
        if($this->connect):
            mysql_select_db($db, $this->connect) or die('( <b>'.$db.'</b> ) NOT.');
            $this->check2('SET NAMES '.$this->meta);
        endif;
    }
```

Comment: Так http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
function sql($login='root', $pass='', $db='test', $host = '127.0.0.1')
{           
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.db.';host='.$host.';charset=utf8';
    try {
        $this->connect = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Подключение не удалось: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```