# Проблематика формирования запроса, содержащего запятую

Tags: php, html, sql

У меня появилась проблема ввода запроса содержащего запятую. Мне нужно считать текст из textarea (html) после чего сформировать запрос в БД (при помощи php). Но если в тексте содержится запятая, то при выполнении запроса получается ошибка. Не могли бы вы подсказать способы решения данной проблемы.

Comment: Добавьте используемый код, пожалуйста. Сложно отвечать когда не видишь код.

Comment: Может хотя бы ошибку покажите что ли ?

Comment: используйте подготовленные запросы. Гугл в помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень надеюсь, что Вы не используете устаревшее расширение mysql, а используете PDO или mysqli. Далее пишу ответ с расчетом на PDO, но в mysqli всё почти то же самое (только в 2-3 раза длиннее обычно).
Проблема, скорее всего, в том, что Вы подставляете значения из $_POST/$_GET прямо в запрос. Для начала:

[Как заменить mysql connect на PDO connect?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/725114/269365)

[Защищают ли подготовленные выражения/переменные полностью от SQL инъекций?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/639411/269365)

[Каким образом избежать SQL-инъекций в PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896/269365)

P.S. не забудьте плюсануть по приведенным ссылкам сами вопросы и ответы на них.
P.P.S. ну и не забудьте почитать просто полезный [материал по PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)